# Editing the CSS of a Form.aspx that has a custom WebPart

Tags: web-part, css, display-form

I have a rich text field that is displaying in small font and light gray. This needs to be dark and larger. Here is the FormField on the customNewForm.aspx.

```
    <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
        <SharePoint:FormField CssClass="fontIncrease" runat="server" id="ff7{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Response_x0020_Body" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff7',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Response_x0020_Body')}"/>
        <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff7description{$Pos}" FieldName="Response_x0020_Body" ControlMode="New"/>
    </td>
```

How do set fontsize and color on this FormField?

Answer (score 1):

What did you put in your CCS class *fontIncrease*

Do other (SharePoint) CSS Selectors have more [CSS Specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity)?

You can make your CSS definitions more !important

```
.fontIncrease{
   font-size:1.5em !important;
   color:grey !important;
}
```

or stick a

```
style="font-size:1.5em;color:grey"
```

attribute on the field

Comment: I can put style="etc..." within the <SharePoint:FormField> tag? alternately, where would I put the css .fontIncrease{ }? Do i put that somewhere on the form? or make a div tag encasing the formfield?